# Удаление элемента из массива

Tags: массивы, c++

Здравствуйте, помогите, пожайлуста, решить задачу на С++. Дано целое число N и набор из N целых чисел. Найти номера первого минимального и последнего максимального элемента из данного набора и вывести их в указанном порядке. Программа вот такой имеет вид, но правильно ли?

```
#include <vcl.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    int a[5];
    int n, i, imax, imin;
    cout << " vvedite n: " << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> a[i];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    for (i = imax = imax = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (a[i] < a[imin])
            imin = i;
        if (a[i] > a[imax])
            imax = i;
    }
    cout << " min=  " << imin;
    cout << " max=  " << imax;
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Неправильно.

Comment: У вас не инициализирована переменная `imin`. и у вас вопрос несколько не точно (а вернее - совсем не про то) указан. при чём здесь удаление элемента массива?

Comment: Я знаю, что не правильно. Потому и прошу вас помочь.

Comment: перепутал вопрос

Comment: @LeD4eG `imin` у ТС объявлен.

Comment: Это вообще к чему :

     Удаление элемента из массива

Но если что, юзайте vector из STL. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А ввод n где? И в цикле исправить инициализацию i на "...i=imax=imin=0;...".
Еще, чтобы из максимальных определить последний, нужно поставить >= в условии
и да нужно объявлять массив размерности n после ввода n.

Comment: @Luchnik95, вот эту строчку в программке Вы видели ?

    for(i=0; i<n; i++) cin >> a[i];

IMHO это ввод n элементов в массив a[].

У автора этот массив уже объявлен (только он очень маленький (int a[5];))

Видимо поэтому его не замечают и не советуют автору сравнивать введенное n с 5-ой.

Но Ваше предложение о вводе n и последующем размещении массива безусловно правильное.

Comment: @avp, Я писал тоже самое, т. к. ТС указал, что у него N элементов, а не строго 5

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем. Вы инициализировали массив как массив, состоящий из 6 элементов, а потом предлагаешь ввести размер будещего массива. А так вроде все правильно.

Comment: Все равно неправильно. 

Наводящий вопрос: *что будет, если все n чисел равны ?*

Напомню:

Найти номера **первого** минимального и **последнего** максимального элемента

Comment: Размер массива???, вообще то программа предлагает указать количество повторений цикла...

Comment: @niki-timofe, оно не должно превышать размер массива.

Comment: @avp программа не выведет ни чего, т. е. нету ни макс. ни мин.

Да, я знаю, так что нужно размер массива не 5, а n, и цикл не до n, а до Ubound(a), или как там в C++

Comment: @niki-timofe, она выведет два нуля. По условию д.б. 0 (min) и 4 (max для 5-ти чисел).

Очень похожий ответ если несколько минимумов-максимумов (не обязательно **все** числа равные).

imin правильно, imax - нет.

Проверять введенное n надо **обязательно**.

Comment: @avp зачем проверять n, разве что только на целочисленность и положительность??, ТС же указал, что из N элементов

Comment: @niki-timofe, оттранслируйте программу, в ответ на " vvedite n: " введите 100000 и Вы станете писать лучше.

Comment: Хорошо, и на то, меньше ли 1000